# receiving error message "the email address is already in use by another account" when attempting to register with new email

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a register page with 3 UITextFields and a register button. When the button is clicked, the account is supposed to be registered to my Firebase Database. However, whenever I click the button, the SVProgressHUD.showSuccess() appears, but so does an UIAlert saying "the email address is already in use by another account" in addition to the preformSegue not occurring. This error cannot be true though because none of the emails I am using are registered to my app.

Below is the code I currently am using:

```
func register() {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: registerEmail.text!, password: registerPassword.text!) { (user, error) in
        if error == nil {
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            SVProgressHUD.showSuccess(withStatus: "Welcome \(self.registerEmail.text!)")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTheHome", sender: self)
        }
        else {
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            print(error as Any)
            print("")
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alert,animated: true)            }
    }

}

@IBAction func createAccount(_ sender: UIButton) {
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    if registerPassword.text == confirmPassword.text {
    register()
    }
    else {
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Passwords do not match", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alert,animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, have you checked you firebase auth console to check whether your error is true or not ??

Comment: yes I have and the error is not true

Answer (score 0):

If the new account was successfully created, the user is signed in, and you can get the user's account data from the result object that's passed to the callback method.

You can try to check your `user` (**result**) object in the console..

Comment: the new account was successfully created. How would I implement the prevention of displaying the error, and how would I preform the segue?